# How to add a nullable column type to an already migrated table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a migration with `$table->datetime('published_at');` 
and it is already migrated and data is filled in. Now, I have to make this column `->nullable()`, but without using `migrate:refresh` or `rollback`. How can I achieve this or is it even possible.

Note: No raw sql queries or phpmyadmin. Looking for migration methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new migration:

```
php artisan make:migration change_published_at_to_nullable
```

This will generate a new Migration file called

```
XXXX_YYY_ZZZ_000000_change_published_at_to_nullable.php
```

In this migration file, add the following code:

```
public function up(){
  Schema::table("table", function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string("published_at")->nullable()->change();
  });
}

public function down(){
  Schema::table("table", function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string("published_at")->nullable(false)->change();
  });
}
```

When the command `php artisan migrate` is run, the `published_at` column will be changed to allow `null`. If you need to reverse this, `php artisan migrate:refresh`, or `php artisan migrate:reset`, or `php artisan migrate:rollback --step` will change the column back to allow `not null`.

Comment: That works! But need to run `composer require doctrine/dbal`  in terminal first. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

create new migration and add code below:

```
Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('published_at')->nullable()->change();
});
```

or if using mysql:

You can change your table's structure directly in phpmyadmin

Go to phpmyadmin -> table -> structure

edit publishd_at column and tick null

Answer (score -1):

Simple way is to just run a query like this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY published_at DATETIME NULL
```

Comment: This is not a question about how to update a column manually using a SQL statement; this is about Laravel migrations: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations

Comment: This isn't updating it manually, this is a raw query that you can run on Laravel migrations in Up() or Down()... lol

Comment: That's not how you use migrations.

Comment: False, if you run php artisan command to make a migration it will spit out a migration file with the up and down functions. From there you can just do  DB::select(DB::raw('') which will then be part of your migrations.

Comment: Once again, that goes against the whole point of using migrations. There's syntax for modifying a column's `null` property, so there is no reason to use a raw statement like that. Also, using a raw statement requires you to know the DBMS being used, while migrations are SQL agnostic, adapting to the driver being used.

Comment: And yet it works just the same and gets ran just like any other migration, it answers the question and provides an alternative solution for him.

Comment: Maybe if you actually had some PHP syntax in your answer it might, but just posting the raw statement doesn't answer the question...

Comment: You shouldn't have to spoon feed anything. That raw query can be included in the migrations or ran on a db editor. The question was I migrated something now I need to tweek it. We didn't say using another migration how do I do this.